# Google Sheets Get Letter from Integer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an integer that I got from getting the number of columns of a range. I want to make that integer a letter so I can make a new range (Columns are letters, Integers are rows). Thank you!

```
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var fromL = dataLetters.getRange(dataL[string.charAt(i)])
    var to = dataWriting.getRange(`${currentc}2:${currentc}11`)
    fromL.copyTo(to, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT,false)
    current += fromL.getNumColumns() //HERE---------------------------------------------
  }
```

I tried to use many different functions but I am lost. Am I missing something? This is sooooo frustrating!!!!!!!!!!!!! MOSTLY CODE BE QUIET PLEASE BLAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Ranges can be “A1” notation where A is column 1 and 1 is row 1.  But there are also numerous methods that use row number and column number such as getRange(2,1) where 2 is the row number and 1 is the column number.  So ther is no need to convert ranges to “A1” notation.

Answer (score 0):

In my early days of Google Apps Script this too drove me crazy. Here was my solution which I hardly ever use nor worry about anymore.

```
function lettertonumbertoletter() {
  let obj = getColumnsObject();
  let o  = ["A","B","C","D","E","MA","LA",26,52,104,208].map(e => [e,obj[e]]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o).replace(/],/g,'],\n'))
}


function getColumnsObject() {
  var cObj = {};
  var chA = [];
  var colA = [];
  for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) { chA.push(String.fromCharCode(i)); }
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        colA.push(chA[j]);
      }
      if (i > 0) {
        colA.push(chA[i - 1] + chA[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < colA.length; i++) {
    cObj[i + 1] = colA[i];
    cObj[colA[i]] = i + 1;
  }
  return cObj;
}

Execution log
5:17:33 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:17:33 PM  Info    [["A",1],
["B",2],
["C",3],
["D",4],
["E",5],
["MA",339],
["LA",313],
[26,"Z"],
[52,"AZ"],
[104,"CZ"],
[208,"GZ"]]
5:17:35 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

run the debugger on getColumnsObject and you will see that it's just a big converter for going from columns to letters and vice versa and it goes quite large.